# How to detect japanese characters on a string using PHP language?

Tags: php

Given the following 3 strings,

String 1 (Japanese with other language words):
"激安価格お買い得タイヨー脱腸帯·片側用 fm 腰回り with any other word"

String 2 (Portuguese):
"isto é um teste."

String 3 (English):
"This is a test"

How can I only identify the String 1 using PHP?

Thks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Since this topic is on hold, I'm gonna try to meet stackoverflow's requirements:

> *"This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself." – Anonymous, jeroen, Hanky 웃 Panky*

I have a problem... :( 
My problem is that I am receiving lots of Spam messages on a reviews system website.
I've noticed that most of them has japanese characters. My bosses said specifically that I can't use any captcha mechanism.

So.... The only thing I can think of is detect japanese characters... like I've mentioned on the title, and described on the post!

Better?
Cheers! :)

Comment: googling `detect japanese characters from text php` already yielded helpful resources. [sample](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### http://ideone.com/s8Mzum

I tried this in Ideone and it works. But it isn't thoroughly tested.

```
   <?php

$word = "激安価格お買い得タイヨー脱腸帯·片側用 fm 腰回り";
$word2 = "This is the english language";

function isJapanese($lang) {
    return preg_match('/[\x{4E00}-\x{9FBF}\x{3040}-\x{309F}\x{30A0}-\x{30FF}]/u', $lang);
}

var_dump(isJapanese($word)); //returns 1
var_dump(isJapanese($word2));//returns 0
```

Comment: Can the down-voter explain the reason? I made a big edit.

Comment: Works perfectly. +1 and accepted answer. Thks a lot!

Comment: Not working for this - https://ideone.com/y8LCgh